# Why doesn't my BlackBerry 10 native app run in landscape orientation?

Tags: blackberry-10

I have a BlackBerry 10 native app which must run in landscape orientation only. I have the following code in my `bar-descriptor.xml` under the `<qnx>` tag:

```
<initialWindow>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
</initialWindow>
```

However, when I launch the app, it always launches in portrait mode. What else do I need to do to make the app launch in landscape mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that as well as the `<initialWindow>` declaration in `bar-descriptor.xml` you must call `navigator_rotation_lock(true)` within your app initialisation code in order to tell the navigator that the orientation is locked.

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/com.qnx.doc.bps.lib_ref/com.qnx.doc.bps.lib_ref/topic/navigator_rotation_lock.html

Answer (score 1):

you must define it at qml file as well, ie. on signal creationComplete

```
onCreationCompleted: {
        OrientationSupport.supportedDisplayOrientation = SupportedDisplayOrientation.DisplayLandscape;
}
```

or in c++, you can define it in the application constructor:

```
OrientationSupport::instance()
      .setSupportedDisplayOrientation(SupportedDisplayOrientation::DisplayLandscape);
```

you check the documentation at : https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/dev/orientation/index.html

Comment: I don't have a QML file, it is a purely C++ app using BlackBerry Platform Services

Comment: I update my answer, please check; I hope it can solve your problem

Comment: Many thanks for the update. Sorry, I should have been more specific: I am not using **Cascades**. It is an OpenGLES app which does not include any of the Cascades libraries so I cannot use the `OrientationSupport` class.

Answer (score 0):

"I turns out" you must call a few things when receiving NAVIGATOR_WINDOW_ACTIVE :

```
    bps_event_t *event = NULL;

    for (;;)
    {
        if (BPS_SUCCESS != bps_get_event(&event, 0))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "bps_get_event failed\n");
            break;
        }

        if (event)
        {
            int domain = bps_event_get_domain(event);

            if (domain == navigator_get_domain())
            {
                UINT ID = bps_event_get_code(event);
                if (ID == NAVIGATOR_EXIT)
                {
                    exit_application = 1;
                }
                else if(ID == NAVIGATOR_WINDOW_ACTIVE)
                {
                   SetRotationDammIt();                                        
                }
             }
         }
     }
     //...
     void SetRotationDammIt()
     {
            int angle = 90;
            screen_set_window_property_iv( screen_win, SCREEN_PROPERTY_ROTATION, &angle);
            navigator_set_orientation(NAVIGATOR_RIGHT_UP, NULL);
     }
```

There's a couple of things left to fix though. You need to switch X with Y for resolution fetches since the window is natively still in portrait mode (X < Y) and you also have to do a switch-aroo with input something like :

```
        float RatioX = TouchX / PortraitX;
        float RatioY = TouchY / PortraitY;
        Vector2 Res( PortraitY, PortraitX );
        Vector2 RealCoords( RatioX * Res.x, RatioY * Res.y );
```

This only seems to happen on the most recent simulator though (Version 10.1.0.1720 and note that I don't have a physical device, just in case this doesn't work for you), on older ones it works with just the manifest setting (for some reason), but I needed this in order to play .wav files cause older ones couldn't.